# Show photo, video, mp3 in system app

Tags: ios

I have one simple desire: Open media like video (MOV), image (JPG) or music (MP3) in the default iOS app for that media.
I tried this for a MOV file which is in the apps documents folder, which has the correct rights set to access that folder, but it never works.
`UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)` is the call I tried, it doesn't work.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Docs say: "*When your app needs to interact with files it cannot preview or open on its own, use a UIDocumentInteractionController object to manage those interactions.*"

Comment: Thanks. I consider this the correct answer. I tried it and it worked. I googled but could only find: "How do I open the media in _my_ app", which isn't helpful at all for my case.
Please post it as answer so I can mark it as correct.